# Alert if dropdown-menu is open - Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I tried:

**1.**

```
if($('.dropdown-menu').css('display') == 'block')
{
  alert(1);
}

if($('.dropdown-menu.show').css('display') == 'block')
{
  alert(1);
}
```

**2.**

```
if ( $( ".dropdown-menu" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {

    alert(1);

}

if ( $( ".dropdown-menu.show" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {

    alert(1);

}
```

**AND**

```
if ($(".dropdown").hasClass("show")) {
  alert(1);
}
```

**standard CSS bootstrap code**

```
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: block;
}
```

It worked with IF `display == none` or `:hidden` but never the other way I don't understand this.

Comment: Is this a navbar drop down or a button dropdown ?

Comment: could you paste the HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried?

```
$("#button").attr("aria-expanded")
```

Note: `#button` is selector here

if dropdown is open in bootstrap it would be `true` else `false`.

**Or**

You can try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")[0].offsetHeight
```

JQuery version of above is:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").offset().top
```

you can use any selector as per requirement here, I preferred class

Which will be 0, if dropdown closed and height of the dropdown menu.

Comment: The first example worked PERFECT thanks for your time